# How to set enum type to String type

Tags: java, enums

I have one java object which is using enum type

```
  public class Deal{

public enum PriceType {
        fixed, hour, month, year
    }

     @Element(name = "price-type", required = false)
     private PriceType priceType;

  }
```

this object is get populated from some API and I am retriving this in database object having string type variable

```
MyDeal{
    private String priceType;

    public String getPriceType() {
    return priceType;
   }

    public void setPriceType(String priceType) {
    this.priceType = priceType == null ? null : priceType.trim();
   }

}
```

why can't I set my database object like

```
 List<Deal>deals = dealResource.getAll(); 
 MyDeal myDeal = new myDeal(); 

 for (Deal deal : deals) {
     myDeal.setPriceType(deal.getPriceType());
 }
```

Comment: You are "setting" with a getter, is it a typo or your bug?

Comment: Sorry  @heikkim it was typo I updated that.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a `PriceType` to a String directly. You need to do something like this

```
for (Deal deal : deals) {
     myDeal.setPriceType(deal.getPriceType().name()); // name() will get that name of the enum as a String
}
```

Though the `for` loop looks seriously flawed. You'll just keep overriding the `priceType` in `myDeal` over and over again.

Comment: its still giving me compilation error. There is other code also in for  loop, this is just a brief explanation about the probem

Answer (score 1):

Add Enumerated to the property

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Element(name = "price-type", required = false)
private PriceType priceType;
```